# Why are ports 30000 to 60000 needed when browsing the net

Tags: internet, port

Why are these iptables rules preventing me from browsing the net?

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 30000:60000 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 30000:60000 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j DROP
```

With `iptables -F` you can clear the iptables rules in case you can not browse the net after trying those rules.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 but I see this also on my Debian server.

Comment: Just a note: these would prevent most TCP/IP clients from working to connect to anyplace on the Internet. There's nothing special about a web browser, these are baked into TCP/IP. You just noticed cause you're using a browser, not say, IRC.

Comment: I actually noticed this while trying to create iptables rules for my server so that I just allow connections to the ports that are really needed. I soon noticed that I needed to open ports somewhere between 30000 and 60000 or Oauth (using Omniauth) would not work at all. Since applying iptables rules I saw random errors in the logs. Now I know those errors came when Oauth tried to use the closed ports 60000 to 61000.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The web browser needs a port for each HTTP request. Those ports are (rarely) chosen by the browser, but by the kernel. The kernel doesn't look at ipfilter rules, it only tries to use a free port. And most of the time the ports between 30000 and 60000 are used.

To see which port range your kernel is trying to use:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
```

You can change those values with:

```
echo 1234 5678 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range   # for immediate effect
```

or edit the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file to keep the settings across reboots.

Edit: as @TomWijsman suggests, the default values are:

```
echo 32768 61000 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
```

Comment: (In case someone messes them up trying, good defaults are [**`32768   61000`**](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0706.1/0101.html))